# How can one iterate through files in folder in natural sort order using glob.glob(path)?

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, iteration, glob

I am currently trying to do something very basic: compute the sum of two cells in a .csv file and output it into a new DataFrame. I then am repeating this for multiple rows in that .csv file, and multiple files in a folder. After all this, I am outputting the DataFrame to a .xlsx file. Main body of code is below:

```
for fname in glob.glob(path):
    print(fname)
    processed = []
    df = pd.read_csv(fname)
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        processed.append(row['Rejected'] + row['Sorted'])
    heatMap[str(counter)] = processed
    counter += 1
```

newfname = 'Output.xlsx'
heatMap.to_excel(newfname)

However, when I look at my newly created DataFrame, the columns are out of order. Inspecting the console, I can see the files are iterated through in a alphanumeric order.

[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8ChA.png)

I was wondering how my method can be adjusted so that I can iterate through the files in a natural sort order (1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc.), so I don't have to change the name of each file.

Thank you!

Comment: paste text instaed of screenshot

Comment: what's **binary order**?

Comment: Post has been edited to have cody body in text instead of a screenshot.

Comment: Post has been edited to remove the term binary order, that was a mistake for me to write that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for fname in sorted(glob.glob(path)):
    ...
```

This makes the glob iteration a list, so that we can sort it using the python `sorted` keyword. You can then loop through it in alphabetical order.

For natural sort, there is a [`natsort`](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/) package.

```
from natsort import natsorted
for fname in natsorted(glob.glob(path)):
    ...
```

Comment: By the way, `glob.glob()` already returns a list so you don't need to call `list` on it.

Comment: My issue still persists, the files are being iterated through in the 1, 10, 11, 12, 13 ... 2, 20, 21, 23.... 3, 30, 31, 32, 33.... etc. pattern.

Comment: this is correct `alphanumerical order`, what you really want is `natual sorting`(there's pypi lib)

Comment: Thank you, I realize I have used alphanumeric incorrectly. This is the correct answer for alphanumeric sort but I am infact looking for natural sorting. I will edit my post.

Comment: Updated my answer to include natural sort

Comment: It works! thank you all.